# How to suggest new computer domain name

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm trying to write a program that search our domain by entered name of groups of computers (for example for IT users computer name beginns with DITXX, where XX is number of computer) and suggest new computer name. For example we have computers:

1. DIT01
2. DIT02
3. ..
4. DIT10
5. DIT11
6. ..
7. DIT156

I have TextBox where i enter group name, then i get a list of computers containing this name and i'm putting them to List and to Array. But how to get last used name and suggest new (here program should suggest name DIT157 beacuse of last name DIT156)? Should i use natural sort? Or trim name DIT to have only numbers, sort them and then just find last, add 1 and then show trimmed name + this number?

Code fragments:

```
string name = textBox1.Text;
DirectoryEntry domain = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://*****.****.**.**");
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(domain);
search.Filter = ("(&(ObjectCategory=computer)(cn=") + name + ("*))");

List<string> temp = new List<string>();

richTextBox1.Text = "";
List<string> ComputerList = new List<string>();

foreach (SearchResult c in search.FindAll())
{
    var tmp = (c.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.ToString());

    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + (tmp.Replace("CN=", "")) + (Environment.NewLine);
    //listView1.Items.Add(tmp.Replace("CN=", ""),2);
    temp.Add (tmp.Replace("CN=", ""));

    ComputerList.Add(tmp.Replace("CN=", ""));
}

ComputerList.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    int ix, iy;
    return int.TryParse(x, out ix) && int.TryParse(y, out iy)
        ? ix.CompareTo(iy) : string.Compare(x, y);
});
string[] Computers = ComputerList.ToArray();
Array.Sort(Computers);

foreach (var item in Computers)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For random computer name generation I personally would try something other than query/sort, like use Random.  Or perhaps append the result of `Path.GetRandomFileName()` to your prefix (strip out the '.') and limit the total length to 15.

If you choose to do the query and sort I would strip off the text and sort by the number alone, because your example computer names have different lengths.  Sorting by string would cause DIT11 and DIT110 to be next to each other in the list.  And if you write a sorting algorithm you will end up stripping off the text anyway.